# Bash script to find matching rows from multiple csv files and create report out of it

Tags: bash, shell

I have three different CSV files. There format is as follows :

```
domain1.csv

name1,lastname1
name2,lastname2
name3,lastname3

domain2.csv

name1,lastname1
name6,lastname6
name3,lastname3

domain3.csv

name1,lastname1
name4,lastname4
name3,lastname3
```

Now based on this three files i need to create report like this

```
name,lastname,domain1,domain2,domain3
name1,lastname1,yes,yes,yes
name2,lastname2,yes,no,no
name3,lastname3,yes,yes,yes
name4,lastname4,no,no,yes
name6,lastname6,no,yes,no
```

Basically this report is only possible using a script which can read rows one by one in each file and find that row in other two files and create the report by matching the name and lastname columns. But i am a total newbie in shell scripting. Can someone help me. I am using bash.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: This is not a "code it for me" site, you're expected to make an attempt, show your code, and explain where you're having trouble. I'll give you a suggestion: use `awk`.

Comment: Seems like something that would be easier to write and maintain moving forward if you could write a Python script instead, can you?

Comment: Any scripting language with associative arrays can also do it pretty easily.

Comment: Dear All, I know this is not code it for me site. I am a complete newbie to scripting/programming. So i have no idea where to start on first place. Thats why i asked for help so after i get the code i can learn from that code.

Comment: Have you at least Googled it, or tried to work with a single file? Your question is showing absolutely no effort to solve it yourself. Everyone can say "Write it for me, and I can learn from that code.". StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, and you need to at least attempt to do something first before posting here. Questions that are a list of requirements and nothing else aren't appropriate here. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is a mini-language that comes standard with most Unix-like operating systems and allows you to tackle this sort of problem fairly easily.

```
awk '{ names[$0] = (names[$0] "," FILENAME) }
     END { print "name,lastname,domain1,domain2,domain3"
           for( elt in names ) {
             printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", elt,
                                     index( names[elt], "domain1.csv" ) ? "yes" : "no",
                                     index( names[elt], "domain2.csv" ) ? "yes" : "no",
                                     index( names[elt], "domain3.csv" ) ? "yes" : "no"
           }
         }' domain*.csv | sort
```

The script above parses each of the files line-by-line and constructs an associative array using `nameN,lastnameN` as the indexes and the filenames that they're found in (separated by commas) as the values. Then it loops through the associative array and prints each index followed by the "yes" or "no" strings depending on whether the array's values contain each filename.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to write this in bash, meaning `while` loops and line-by-line comparison, because that's just too much pain and slow. The shell has a lot of tools available. One which comes in handy in this case is called `join` (relational database context: this would be Cartesian product or cross join because of -a1 -a2). Provided your .csv files are sorted (see the shell command `sort`)

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 dom1.csv dom2.csv
```

gives

```
name1,lastname1,lastname1

name2,lastname2

name3,lastname3,lastname3

name6,lastname6
```

Note the third column. It is empty if the line does not appear in both files. So this solves half your problem. Then you can try to use `sed` or `awk` to change the last column if it is non-empty with yes/no as per your requirement. And of course, nothing prevents you from running `join` again on the result against the third file, and massaging the output to contain yes/no.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command with `sort` and `sed` are the primary tools needed.  Assume that `:` does not appear in the original data.  To record the presence of a row in a file, we want a `yes` field in the file; we'll have `join` supply the `no` when there isn't a match.  Using `bash`'s process substitution, we can write:

```
$ sed 's/$/:yes/' domain1.csv | sort |
> join -t: -a 1 -a 2 -e no -o 0,1.2,2.2     - <(sed s'/$/:yes/' domain2.csv | sort) |
> join -t: -a 1 -a 2 -e no -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - <(sed 's/$/:yes/' domain3.csv | sort) |
> sed 's/:/,/g'
name1,lastname1,yes,yes,yes
name2,lastname2,yes,no,no
name3,lastname3,yes,yes,yes
name4,lastname4,no,no,yes
name6,lastname6,no,yes,no
$
```

The `sed` and `sort` combos (three times) add the `:yes` to the files and sort the names.  The joins are very nearly symmetric.  The `-t:` specifies that the field separator is the colon; the `-a 1` and `-a 2` mean that when there isn't a match in a file, the line will still be included in the output; the `-e no` means that if there isn't a match in a file, a `no` is generated in the output; and the `-o` option specifies the output columns.  For the first join, `-o 0,1.2,2.2` the output is the join column (`0`), then the second column (the `yes`) from the two files.  The second join has 3 columns in the input, so it specifies `-o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2`.  The argument `-` on its own means 'read standard input'. The `<(...)` notation is 'process substitution', where a file name (usually `/dev/fd/NN`)  is provided to the `join` command, and it contains the output of the command inside the parentheses. The output is then filtered through `sed` once more to replace the colons with commas, yielding the desired output.