# bash: clean outer join of three files, preserving file-membership

Tags: bash, awk, outer-join

Consider the following three files with headers in the first row:

file1:

```
id name in1
1 jon 1
2 sue 1
```

file2:

```
id name in2
2 sue 1
3 bob 1
```

file3:

```
id name in3
2 sue 1
3 adam 1
```

I want to merge these files to get the following output, merged_files:

```
id name in1 in2 in3
1 jon 1 0 0
2 sue 1 1 1
3 bob 0 1 0
3 adam 0 0 1
```

This request has several special features that I have not found implemented in a handy way in grep/sed/awk/join etc.  Edit:  You may assume, for simplicity, that the three files have already been sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to the problem solved in [Bash script to find matching rows from multiple CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459789/bash-script-to-find-matching-rows-from-multiple-csv-files-and-create-report-out/17460732#17460732).  It's not identical, but it is very similar.  (So similar that I only had to remove three `sort` commands, change the three `sed` commands slightly, change the file names, change the 'missing' value from `no` to `0`, and change the replacement in the final `sed` from comma to space.)

The `join` command with `sed` (usually `sort` too, but the data is already sufficiently sorted) are the primary tools needed. Assume that `:` does not appear in the original data. To record the presence of a row in a file, we want a `1` field in the file (it's almost there); we'll have `join` supply the `0` when there isn't a match. The `1` at the end of each non-heading line needs to become `:1`, and the last field in the heading also needs to be preceded by the `:`.  Then, using `bash`'s [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), we can write:

```
$ sed 's/[ ]\([^ ]*\)$/:\1/' file1 |
> join -t: -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,2.2     - <(sed 's/[ ]\([^ ]*\)$/:\1/' file2) |
> join -t: -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - <(sed 's/[ ]\([^ ]*\)$/:\1/' file3) |
> sed 's/:/ /g'
id name in1 in2 in3
1 jon 1 0 0
2 sue 1 1 1
3 adam 0 0 1
3 bob 0 1 0
$
```

The `sed` command (three times) adds the `:` before the last field in each line of the files. The joins are very nearly symmetric. The `-t:` specifies that the field separator is the colon; the `-a 1` and `-a 2` mean that when there isn't a match in a file, the line will still be included in the output; the `-e 0` means that if there isn't a match in a file, a `0` is generated in the output; and the `-o` option specifies the output columns. For the first join, `-o 0,1.2,2.2` the output is the join column (0), then the second column (the `1`) from the two files. The second join has 3 columns in the input, so it specifies `-o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2`. The argument `-` on its own means 'read standard input'. The `<(...)` notation is 'process substitution', where a file name (usually `/dev/fd/NN`) is provided to the join command, and it contains the output of the command inside the parentheses. The output is then filtered through `sed` once more to replace the colons with spaces, yielding the desired output.

The only difference from the desired output is the sequencing of `3 bob` after `3 adam`; it is not particularly clear on what basis you ordered them in reverse in your desired output.  If it is crucial, a means can be devised for resolving the order differently (such as `sort -k1,1 -k3,5`, except that sorts the label line after the data; there are workarounds for that if necessary).

Comment: FYI: if you omit the `-o` specification, you do not get the zeros substituted in the result for missing values (at least with BSD `join` on Mac OS X 10.8.5) — that's why the `-o` specifications are there.  Slightly odd behaviour...

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
{
if ($1=="id") { v[i++]=$3; next }
b[$1,$2]=$1" "$2
c[i-1,$1" "$2]=$3
}

END {
printf ("id name")
for (x in v) printf (" %s", v[x]); printf ("\n")
for (y in b)  {
    printf ("%s", b[y])
    for (z in v) if (c[z,b[y]]==0) {printf (" 0")} else printf (" %s", c[z,b[y]])
    printf ("\n")
    }
}
```

```
$cat file?
id name in1
1 jon 1
2 sue 1
id name in2
2 sue 1
3 bob 1
id name in3
2 sue 1
3 adam 1

$awk -f prog.awk file?
id name in1 in2 in3
3 bob 0 1 0
3 adam 0 0 1
1 jon 1 0 0
2 sue 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` script will do what you want:

```
$1=="id"&&$2=="name"{
    ins[$3]= 1;
    lastin = $3;
}
$1!="id"||$2!="name" {
    ids[$1] = 1;
    names[$2] = 1;
    a[$1,$2,lastin]= $3
    used[$1,$2] = 1;
}
END {
    printf "id name"
    for (i in ins) {
        printf " %s", i
    }
    printf "\n"
    for (id in ids) {
        for (name in names) {
            if (used[id,name]) {
                printf "%s %s", id, name
                for (i in ins) {
                    printf " %d", a[id,name,i]
                }
                printf "\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming your files are called `list1`, `list2`, etc., and the awk file is `script.awk`, you can run it like this

```
$ cat list* | awk -f script.awk
id name in1 in2 in3
1 jon 1 0 0
2 sue 1 1 1
3 bob 0 1 0
3 adam 0 0 1
```

I am sure that is a much shorter and simpler way to do it, but this is all I could come up with at 1:30 am :)

Comment: I like the clear format of this solution, in contrast to the sed/join approach.  However, I'm having trouble getting it to work.  My actual application has an additional variable, so I modified the code to include yet another innermost loop.  With ~200k lines in each file, my macbook was dying, and I killed it after a few minutes of run time.  If you'd expect this to be faster, let me know, and I'll re-check my implementation.