# How to grep two column from a single file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

cat Error00

```
4  0    375
4 2001   21
4 2002   20
```

cat Error01

```
4 0      465
4 2001   12
4 2002   40
4 2016   1
```

I want output as below

```
4 0      375   465
4 2001   21    12
4 2002   20    20
4 2016   -     1
```

i am using the below query. here problem is i m not able to handle grep for two field because space is coming. 
please suggest how can to get rid of this.

```
keylist=$(awk '{print $1,$2'} Error0[0-1] | sort | uniq)
for key in ${keylist} ; do
echo ${key}
        val_a=$(grep "^${key}" Error00 | awk  '{print $3}') ;val_a=${val_a:---}
        val_b=$(grep "^${key}" Error01 | awk '{print $1,$2}') ; val_b=${val_b:---    --}
        echo $key  ${val_a} >>testreport
done
```

i m geting the oputput as below

```
4       375   465
0
4       21    12
2001
4       20    20
2002
4       -     1
2016
```

Comment: There are multiple questions on this site about how to join two files in Awk. You are not explaining how to obtain the desired output (there appears to be nontrivial reordering of the input fields) so it's hard to provide actual working code. Please elaborate on this, or derive something like `awk '{k=$1":"$2}NR==FNR { a[k]=$3;b[k]=$4;  ...next; } { print $1, $2, b[k], $7, a[k], ... }'` from earlier questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not really the right tool for this job.  You can either play with `awk` or Perl (or Python, or …), or you can use `join`.  However, `join` only joins on a single column at a time, and you appear to need to join on two columns.  So, we're going to have to massage the data so that it will work with `join`.  I'm about to assume you're using `bash` and so have [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) available.  You can do the job without, but it is fiddlier and involves temporary files (and traps to clean them up, etc).

The key to the join will be to replace the blank between the first two columns with a colon (or any other convenient character — control-A would work fine too), then join the files on column 1 with a replacement character.  The inputs must be sorted; the output must have the colon replaced with a blank.

```
$ join -o 0,1.2,2.2 -a 1 -a 2 -e '-' \
>     <(sed 's/  */:/' Error00 | sort) \
>     <(sed 's/  */:/' Error01 | sort) |
> sed 's/:/ /'
4 0 375 465
4 2001 21 12
4 2002 20 40
4 2016 - 1
$
```

The `'s/  */:/'` operation replaces the first sequence of one or more blanks with a colon; the input data has two blanks between the 4 and the 0 in the first line of `Error00`.  The input to `join` must be in sorted order of the joining field, here the first field.  The output is the join field, the second column of `Error00` and the second column of `Error01` (remembering that means the second column after the first two have been fused by the colon).  If there's an unmatched line in the first file, generate an output line (`-a 1`); ditto for the second file; and for the missing fields, insert a dash (`-e '-'`).  The final `sed` removes the colon that was added.

If you want the data formatted, pipe it through `awk`.

```
$ join -o 0,1.2,2.2 -a 1 -a 2 -e '-' \
>     <(sed 's/  */:/' Error00 | sort) \
>     <(sed 's/  */:/' Error01 | sort) |
> sed 's/:/ /' |
> awk '{printf("%s %-6s %-6s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
4 0      375    465
4 2001   21     12
4 2002   20     40
4 2016   -      1
$
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan 
 That's  really helpful, Thanks a lot . Actually  i did a mistake while posting this thread. i have 15 files not 2 Error00 to Error15, there i can not use Join. So i have use awk here . can you please suggest for that.

Comment: I have got the solution  using tr command 

 
newkey=`echo $key | tr "|" " "`
       echo ${newkey} ${val_a}"  " ${val_b}"  " ${val_c} >>testreport

Comment: There's an extension to 3 files in [Clean outer join of three files preserving file membership](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507765/bash-clean-outer-join-of-three-files-preserving-file-membership). There's a generalization to N files in [What is the simplest method to join columns from a variable number of files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466662/what-is-the-simplest-method-to-join-columns-from-variable-number-of-files-using) There are `awk`-based answers for each.  But please remember to ask the real question up front — we can only answer what you ask.

Answer (score 4):

A single `awk` one liner can handle this easily:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}{print $1,$2,(a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]:"-"),$3}' err0 err1
4 0 375 465
4 2001 21 12
4 2002 20 40
4 2016 - 1
```

For formatted output you can use `printf` instead of `print`. Like [**Jonathan Leffler**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18910603/1066031) suggest:

```
printf "%s %-6s %-6s %s\n",$1,$2,(a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]:"-"),$3
4 0      375    465
4 2001   21     12
4 2002   20     40
4 2016   -      1
```

However a general solution is to use `column -t` for a nice table output:

```
awk '{....}' err0 err1 | column -t
4  0     375  465
4  2001  21   12
4  2002  20   40
4  2016  -    1
```

Comment: Be aware that `column` is not a POSIX command, so it is not available everywhere (Solaris, HP-UX, AIX being likely 'not available' platforms).  That is not to knock this solution, which works reasonably well for the two file case (but observe that there's a problem if the order of the two files is reversed — or both files have entries that are not in the other).